# SharePoint 2013 WF does not see Reusable 2010 WF output variables

Tags: sharepoint-designer, reusable-workflow, custom-workflow

I am using a SP 2013 workflow to take advantage of stages and loops; I call SP 2010 task workflows to take advantage of Impersonation, InfoPath and other 2010 WF features. If I call a SP 2010 List WF from SP 2013 WF, I can use the SP 2010 WF variables in the SP 2013 WF. If I call a SP 2010 reusable WF (easier to deploy to STAGE and PROD), I cannot see the SP 2010 Output variables for the SP 2010 reusable WF.

Is this a limitation or am I missing some way to utilize these variables.